# Jenkins pipeline throwing 'go: command not found' error while running shell script

Tags: bash, go, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

I am trying to create pipeline using blue ocean(jenkins), but i am getting this error:

[image: Error message]

I have performed all the steps (linking github, creating stage etc.) and while creating the pipeline I used shell script to test the command `go test ./...` as step.

Here is the link of the repo https://github.com/SajjanYadav/go-webapp-sample

I tried to find the solution and got to know that may be the path of go is not in the path variable, but even after adding the path (`PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin`) the error keeps on coming.

Comment: How did you add the path /usr/local/go/bin to the PATH environment variable? By adding it to .bashrc?

Answer (score 0):

As [@David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9897703/david) commented, it depends on how you update your `PATH` variable. If you're trying to add `go` only in your [Jenkinsfile](https://github.com/SajjanYadav/go-webapp-sample/blob/master/Jenkinsfile), you might be better off using `environment { PATH = '/usr/local/go/bin:$PATH }` or use `withEnv(PATH='$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin') { sh 'go test' }`